# Firebase: Realtime Database - extreme data usage

Tags: database, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, handshake

So we're working with the Firebase Realtime Database and have encountered some issues regarding the data usage. Currently the total database data comes to a clean 4MB and all we're really GET'ing with every single call made to the RTDB is a single boolean and then a set of 2 strings, basically.

Structure is similar to this:

```
 - Root >

 ------ child 1 >
 ------- child 1.2 >
 -------- child 1.3 >
 --------- value  :  true

 ------ child 2 >
 ------- child 2.1 >
 -------- child 2.2 >
 --------- child 2.3 > 
 ---------- amount : 1
```

Now all we do is get our listener straight into Child 1.3 from root and get its value with

```
firebaseRTDatabase.child("child1.1/child1.2/child1.3/value").addValueEventListener()
```

Then if that value is true, we listen into the second data set like so

```
firebaseRTDatabase.child("child2/child2.1/child2.2").limitToLast(1).addChildEventListener()
```

Then whenever that finds a new child it will handle it within the app.

Issue now is: With the data that the "usage" tab gives us and a bit of calculus it seems that every connection made consumes about 330 MB, almost our full database. As if every connection downloads the whole table, but that shouldn't really be the case right?

I've also noticed that even when idle and unused at least once an hour something is still triggered, even without any events happening. I thought this had to do with FB token refresh and Auth stuff, but manually updating my token after 59 minutes does not solve it and this means we get a classic FB handshake once an hour on every device, which of course also leads to some big usage as this handshake feels bigger than any data we are trying to retrieve.

Anyone have any thoughts on this? Does it indeed seem strange, or is this just expected and a normal usage amount for RTDB?

So, in short:

1. Is there a way to make sure we don't download anything off RTDB that we don't need?
2. Is it plausible that we are downloading the full extend of the table or child at any one point?
3. Is there a way around the hourly handshake happening?

I'm not sure what info to give you. I think this is sufficient but feel free to ask for stuff!

Thanks in advance peeps! :)

Comment: The Firebase Realtime Database SDK only downloads nodes from the database that you attach a listener to, or nodes that you've called `keepSynced(true)` on. If it downloads the entire database, did you by any chance call `keepSynced(true)` on the root somewhere?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen double checked but that's not being called anywhere.  I think it has more to do with the handshake tbh, but since tokens expire every hour I don't really see a way around it..

Comment: I have never seen the SDK download the entire database around an auth handshake, so suspect it's something specific around your project. The code you shared seems fine and in line with what most developers would use to read a deeply nested node. We may be able to say more you can create a clearer [minimal repro](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Hmm, I'll see if I can find some time today to create a repro, but honestly there isn't much more code to it than this. I've been thinking that maybe I'm looking at it the wrong way.
I did create a barebones earlier, so I'll probably upload that one as repro, but the problem persisted although in smaller quantities of course. Really think it's the hourly refresh that's screwing me up, but there seems no workaround for that since creating a new key manually did not solve anything. There's still hourly usage without any listeners being triggered (no activity in the DB at all).

Comment: There's really not enough code or details in the question to understand where the issue could be. For example; this function `addValueEventListener` adds a value event listener and downloads *everything* in that node *every time* there's a change of any kind. So if that node contain 100Mb or data and you change one thing in any child node, say make a single true value false, ALL of the data is re-downloaded. Also, the code in the question doesn't match  your example structure `"child1/child2/child3/value"` and the structure is child 1/child 1.2/... so we need a bit more accurate data.

Comment: Okay well I still don't know what info to give you? So can you be more precise? I changed the error in the code, but there's nothing more to it than this.. This is literally what we're dealing with. So just a boolean pair in a child and an integer pair under the other.

According to what you said however: If the child2.2 listener gets a new child (let's say child2.3-2) , it will download the child2.3 node again as well? :s on an AddChildEvent listener?

Comment: When a listener is applied to a node, Firebase will notify the app of changes. If it's added, changed or removed, only those specific events will fire. If value is used, any change of any kind is returned along with the entire contents of the node. If the value is a bool, then you will only get that one piece of data. However, the code adds a listener to `("child2/child2.1/child2.2")` which means that everything within 2.2 (2.3 and all of it's child data) is returned any time there's a change. While it's limited it to (1), that in itself could the 2.3 node and all child data. What's in 2.2?